# Eclipse on OS X - Can't add a Debug Configuration

Tags: eclipse, macos

Does anyone know why when I press the new button in Eclise Debug Configuration under C/C++ Application nothing happens?

Creating a new Java test configuration does work but I need to create a C/C++ Debug configration. I was able to with ease (on the same project) under linux.

This is under OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by creating a sample C/C++ project and adding the debug configuration there. The configuration is then available to the Java (Android Native) project.

Strange as the project already has the CDT nature added to it.